# Principled BSDF shows values in percentage?

Tags: materials

I must've hit a wrong key but I don't know which one: my Principled BSDF shows percentages now instead of the normal values. Can someone help me put it back? I searched online but I can't seem to find this one. English is not my main language btw.

[image: Principled BSDF in percentages]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this back to 'Factor'.

[image]

A link to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/2.81/editors/preferences/interface.html#editors).